# How do I disable my SASS and .scss files from being compiled to minified .css?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I am trying to verify my updates are being made correctly to my .css files, but my sass.js script (below) is not only compiling the sass files to css but also minifying them? I am not using the ":compressed" option on my .pipe(sass() so I am not certain why this is happening.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const pxtorem = require('gulp-pxtorem');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');

const src = './source';
const dest = './.tmp';
const css = `${src}/styles`;

gulp.task('sass', () =>
  gulp
    .src(`${css}/**/*.s+(a|c)ss`)
    .pipe(
      plumber({
        errorHandler: function errors(err) {
          errorMessage(err, 'CSS error');
          this.emit('end');
        },
      })
    )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        cascade: false,
      })
    )
    .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
    .pipe(pxtorem())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/styles`))
);

/** ****************************************************************** */
/** ****************************************************************** */
/** ****************************************************************** */
/** ****************************************************************** */
/** ****************************************************************** */
/** ****************************************************************** */

function errorMessage(err, title) {
  notify.onError({
    actions: 'Close',
    message: `Error: ${title}: ${err}`,
    sound: 'Purr',
    subtitle: 'Check console for errors',
    timeout: 30,
  })(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package responsible for minifying your css file is cleanCss("gulp-clean-css"), and to solve your issue, please follow next steps =>

- 1 => you finally will have to minify your css file so you can use it,
  but as I got your question, that you need a beautified(not-miniefied)
  css file so you can compare your last changes and make sure of them.
- 2 => you can generate both beautified(not-miniefied) and minified versions
  of your css file at the same time
- 3 => you just need to change your gulp script to the below

```
gulp.task('sass', () =>
         gulp
           .src(`${css}/**/*.s+(a|c)ss`)
           .pipe(
             plumber({
               errorHandler: function errors(err) {
                 errorMessage(err, 'CSS error');
                 this.emit('end');
               },
             })
           )
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
           .pipe(
             autoprefixer({
               cascade: false,
             })
           )
           .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/styles`)) // => generating not-minified css file beofore minifying
    
           .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' })) // continue processing the file
           .pipe(pxtorem())
    
           .pipe(rename({ suffix: '-min' })) // adding suffix "-min" to differentiate between the 2 files
    
        
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
           .pipe(gulp.dest(`${dest}/styles`))
       );
```

- 4 => don't forget to install gulp-rename and add it to requires

```
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
```

- 5 => I hope this helps you, thanks.